# How to train only for specific entity labels in spaCy?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp, spacy

I want to update an existing spacy model that has the following entity labels:

```
('CARDINAL',  'DATE',  'EVENT',  'FAC',  'GPE',  'LANGUAGE',  'LAW',  'LOC',  'MONEY', 'NORP',
 'ORDINAL',  'ORG',  'PERCENT',  'PERSON',  'PRODUCT',  'QUANTITY',  'TIME',  'WORK_OF_ART')
```

However, I only want to update ('ORG','GPE','PERSON','PRODUCT') while keeping the rest the same. How to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do that is to sample predictions from your original model with the labels you want to keep, and to add in those examples as training data while training your model with the new examples from the labels you want to update. This will ensure the model does not "forget" how to do the labels you want to keep, while learning the new ones.

More information can be found here: https://explosion.ai/blog/pseudo-rehearsal-catastrophic-forgetting